# What's the meaning of "a willy-willy wag"?

Tags: word-meaning

> Tree of mine, tree of mine,
>
> Have you seen a girl
>
> **With a willy-willy wag**, and a long-tailed bag,
>
> Who's stole my money, all I had?'

This is from an English fairy tale "The Old Witch". This was said by a witch, when she run after a girl who stole a great bag of money of her and arrived at a tree which a girl hid behind. What's the meaning of "a willy-willy wag"?

Comment: I suspect Fumble is right, and it's more of a nonsense expression than anything else. By the way, I'd like to know what a _long-tailed bag_ is, too.

Answer (score 4):

It's a "nonsense expression" similar to [*with a hey nonny-nonny*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nonny-nonny) (which was "popularized" by [Shakespeare](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20060810204301AAMNlvE)), but I don't recall hearing OP's example before. Nearly all instances I can easily find online are specific to [The Old Witch](http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/eng/meft/meft22.htm) as cited by OP.

It doesn't really make any difference if some enterprising scholar manages to find etymological references suggesting it *does* (or *did*) mean something specific. If people today don't know what it means, it *really* doesn't mean anything.

Comment: But it does have a *little* meaning, doesn't it? A ***wag*** can refer to the way someone walks or runs. The ***willy-willy*** part seems a bit silly-silly.

Comment: For all we know, it could mean "with a pony-tail". **stole** is the past participle there, BTW.

Comment: @Ringo: But that's precisely my point! In OP's *specific* context, ***wag*** no more means "shake or sway" than it does "wives and girlfriends"! For what it's worth, here's [a similar "nonsense" instance](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22maids+to+see+my+father%27s+geese%22) of ***with a willy-willy*** in "Ballads, Songs and Rhymes of East Anglia" which looks like a version of "OId McDonald Had a Farm". Arguably in *that* context it's an onomatapoeic representation of the sound of geese, but I seriously doubt there's was ever any meaning at all in the Old Witch context.

Comment: I suppose you're right. My thought was that the witch saw the girl running away and noticed the way she wagged, which is a little bit of a stretch maybe. I like the idea of the ponytail wagging. I guess there's a distinction between the author intending something which has become inscrutable and the author intending nothing at all. People who lived back then may have understood it better, but eithe way it's lost to us now.